# Configure Webpack when React is loading from cdn in script tag

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a situation where I'd like to load React and ReactDOM via a script tag from a cdn.

For this to work I need to tell webpack("webpack": "^3.8.1") to not translate 'import React' lines to requires because React will be available in the browser as a global. Given I'm not bundling React those are failing.

Although I can avoid the imports in my code, I don't have that ability in the components I'm importing.

I've tried the following.

Setting up externals in the config.

```
externals: {
    react: {
      root: 'React',
      commonjs2: 'react',
      commonjs: 'react',
      amd: 'react',
      umd: 'react',
    },
    'react-dom': {
      root: 'ReactDOM',
      commonjs2: 'react-dom',
      commonjs: 'react-dom',
      amd: 'react-dom',
      umd: 'react-dom',
    },
  }
```

Using the webpack ignore plugin

```
plugins: [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^(React|react|ReactDOM|react-dom)$/)
    ]
```

and using this module.noParse

```
const noParse = require('react-noparse').noParse;
module.noParse: /^(React|react|ReactDOM|react-dom)$/
```

Done quite a bit of searching, haven't found a solution. Any direction would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked. Maybe this is common knowledge, on the other hand maybe it will help someone else. Would have been useful to me yesterday.

I read a post at https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1275 about creating
one line dummy files that export React and ReactDOM as in

module.exports = window.React;

and then adding a reference to those files in the alias section.

```
alias: {
    "react": "./dummyReact.js",
    "react-dom": "./dummyReactDOM.js"
}
```

That worked but as it turns out, adding externals correctly causes webpack to follow that same pattern.

Putting this in externals

```
externals: {
    'react': 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    "mylibrary": "MyLibrary"
}
```

causes webpack to output the following modules which will expect these references to be in your environment's globals.

```
/* 2 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = React;

/***/ }),
/* 3 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = ReactDOM;

/***/ }),
/* 4 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = MyLibrary;

/***/ })
```